# .git/info/exclude works only for the files in root folder

Tags: git

Not sure why I can exclude files only in root folder of a project. If I place it in some subfolders it won't be excluded. But I can exclude files at any hierarchy level in other projects! Cannot figure out what is so special on this one...

I have used the following commands from the root project directory to illustrate the problem:

```
# Create a file
$ echo "test" > test.txt

# Untracked file detected
$ git status
On branch main
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        test.txt

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

# Exclude it
$ echo "test.txt" >> .git/info/exclude 

# Isn't untracked anymore
$ git status
On branch main
nothing to commit, working tree clean

# Create a file with the same name in a subfolder
$ echo "test" > my-project/src/main/resources/test.txt

# Is untracked anyway
$ git status
On branch main
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        my-project/src/main/resources/test.txt

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Using:
git version 2.34.1

Below are the contents of .git/info/exclude

```
$ cat -et .git/info/exclude 
# git ls-files --others --exclude-from=.git/info/exclude$
# Lines that start with '#' are comments.$
# For a project mostly in C, the following would be a good set of$
# exclude patterns (uncomment them if you want to use them):$
# *.[oa]$
# *~$
test.txt$
```

And below are the contents of .gitignore:

```
$ cat -et .gitignore 
**/target/**$
!**/src/**$
.metadata$
.settings$
.classpath$
.project$
.idea$
*.iml$
```

Comment: There's the `**/test.txt` pattern to exclude a file or folder from anywhere in the repo. Or else you're explicitly asking to exclude only the exact `test.txt` path.

Comment: Can we see your `.git/info/exclude`? Please [edit] and add the exact text output from `cat -et .git/info/exclude`

Comment: @RomainValeri Doesn't pattern `test.txt` mean "exclude at any level"? It doesn't contain a slash.

Comment: @phd I see in [the doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format) that `A leading "**" followed by a slash means match in all directories. For example, "**/foo" matches file or directory "foo" anywhere, the same as pattern "foo". "**/foo/bar" matches file or directory "bar" anywhere that is directly under directory "foo".` But maybe `.git/info/exclude` and `.gitignore` behave differently for this?

Comment: @RomainValeri "\*\*/foo" matches file or directory "foo" anywhere, **the same as pattern "foo"** — emphasize mine. "*But maybe `.git/info/exclude` and `.gitignore` behave differently for this?*" I don't think so. Please do a local experiment.

Comment: @phd I've added the contents of the files

Comment: @RomainValeri It shouldn't matter from my experience. But I also tried with `**/test.txt` and it didn't help.

Comment: I figured it out.

`!**/src/**` in .gitignore was the culprit. The other projects don't have it.

Comment: Patterns from `.git/info/exclude` are evaluated before `.gitignore` so unignore in `.gitignore` has higher priority. Use [`git check-ignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore): `git check-ignore -v my-project/src/main/resources/test.txt` to see which rules apply to what files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. `!**/src/**` in .gitignore was the culprit.

Patterns from `.git/info/exclude` are evaluated before `.gitignore` so unignore in `.gitignore` has higher priority. Use git [check-ignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore): `git check-ignore -v my-project/src/main/resources/test.txt` to see which rules apply to what files.